# Messaging.InboundEmailHandler Failure Scenarios

Tags: apex, email, inboundservices

We are using `Messaging.InboundEmailHandler` to send bounced email on receiving mails from customers having a different mail subject (which is not in a format we expect). And setting `InboundEmailResult` result to `false` in those scenarios, but the bounce email is not triggered to the user. Success scenarios are working fine. What all settings do we need to verify to check to resolve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE; this question is a little confusing and I suggest using [edit] to reword the question (for example a diagram of the flow of operations between actors and processes.

Comment: Messaging.InboundEmailHandler is not for sending emails, it is for writing your own inbound email handler, so I am not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MarcDBehr  We are using that to read/receive mails from custmer and based on that we need to do some action or send response back to customer if its not ina particular format. I believe that can be achieved as per the documentation. [link] https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_using.htm

Comment: OK, got it. We may need to see the code you are trying to use to figure out the issue, but from a high level, the Messaging.InboundEmailHandler should accept in incoming email and then call the Messaging.SingleEmailMessage() method to send the reply message. You should also just use the email2case feature and an process builder to send the reply to skip using code completely

Comment: thanks all.This was solved, actually the Outgoing Email Settings for the context user was changed to  use gmail instead of Salesforce somehow.